# React api request gives me undefined even when using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm making a weather app with react and react-router-dom
now when I make the api request and I set it into state
and that later i try to acces a specific value of that object I get undefined. I know that i wrote the path correct but I keep getting undefined
this is the error I get : TypeError: Cannot read property 'IconPhrase' of undefined

and this is the code:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const URL =
  "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/1761?apikey=tCl4ePcWJ4pcpzDCWO51JkxmOLgPjZOM&language=nl-NL&details=true&metric=true";

function Weather() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => data.DailyForecasts)
      .then((days) => setWeather(days[0]));
  }, []);

  console.log(weather);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="ImageDisplay">
          <div
            className="InnerDisplay"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url("../src/heavyrain.svg")` }}
          >
            <span className="Degrees">{`${weather.Day.IconPhrase}`}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Weather;
```

[image]

Comment: Does the answer help? If yes can you please mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Because you use initial of `weather` is `[]` and when the first render, weather still is `[]`. It just updates when API call success in `useEffect`
You need to fix 2 places:

- `[weather, setWeather] = useState({});` It helps your code clean.
- `${weather?.Day?.IconPhrase}`. It helps fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you make the request in `useEffect`. Hence the components renders once already before request is being made and initially weather variable is an empty array because of `const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);` if you check weather before chain you will be fine.

```
.... 
 <span className="Degrees">{`${weather ?weather.Day.IconPhrase:""}`}</span>
```

Comment: if I dont place it in the useEffect that I get hunderds of console logs

Comment: all side effects should be in useEffect. that approach is right.

Comment: Okay I'll try that to

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is check the `weather.Day` before rendering. You can use conditional rendering for that.

```
{weather.Day && <span className="Degrees">{`${weather.Day.IconPhrase}`}</span>}
```

Also, your fetch URL needed `https` for my demo (just in case)

here is the sandbox working, check the console in there.

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wildflower-s2j4u?file=/src/App.js:769-848